# Не выводит сумму столбца mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю так

```
<?php $result3 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM 
incoming WHERE 
incdate='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$date)." ' ")  or die("<p>Не удается 
выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));  
while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3 )) { 
echo $row3['TotalOrdered'];}
?>
```

Но команда echo ничего не выводи на экран ...в чем может быть проблема ?

Если в phpmyadmin выполнять этот вопрос вот таким вот способом 
    `SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM incoming WHERE incdate='2017-10-25'`
т е с одинарными кавычками то выводит нормаль...как на php написать такой запрос

Comment: попробуйте вывести `echo SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM 
incoming WHERE 
incdate='".mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$date)." ' "` и далее выполнить этот запрос в phpmyadmin или чем-нибудь подобным

Comment: тысяча извинений но phpmyadmin тоже выводит NULL

Comment: Если в phpmyadmin выполнить такой запрос SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM incoming WHERE incdate='2017-10-25'
то есть с одинарными то выводит нормально

Comment: @AlexStassov Проблема в пробеле после двойной кавычки видимо `mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$date)." '` ←

Comment: И без пробела тоже такая фигня (((

Comment: Покажи запрос при котором  "phpmyadmin тоже выводит NULL".... кстати, а зачем в дате `mysqli_real_escape_string`? И почему не используешь подготовленные выражения?

Comment: SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM incoming WHERE incdate=2017-10-25 вот этот запрос где выводит NULL на PHPmyadmn, а так всё нормально SELECT SUM(sum) AS TotalOrdered  FROM incoming WHERE incdate='2017-10-25'

Comment: @AlexStassov, var_dump($date) в студию, пожалуйста.

Comment: Александр Белинский, var_dump($date) дал следующее string(10) "25.10.2017" string(10) "25.10.2017" string(10) "25.10.2017"

Comment: тьфу ((( забыл что там стоит strtotime (((, а дата то была кривая ((( всё заработало

Comment: Александр Белинский спасибо за подсказку ! Так же спасибо Алексею Шиманскому и всем оставльным за помощь друзья. Кстати насчет подготовленных выражениях надо сделать чтоб облегчить жизнь